# Parsear cadena String para suma, resta,división y multiplicación

Tags: java, eclipse, parsear

para parsear una cadena para poder realizar una operación; por ejemplo, introduzco por teclado (2x3) y que me coja el operador x como multiplicación o (-) como resta. Creo que con Parseint es posible, pero no sé muy bien como implementarlo. Alguien tiene un ejemplo?

Comment: Puedes utilizar el método `split` para separar los dos números del operador y luego pasarlos a `int` con el método ´parseInt´.

Comment: Yo usaría `charAt`, busca info que te puede servir

Comment: Aclarar que para multiplicar es **(2 * 3)** en lugar de **(2 x 3)** . Tienes algo de código de lo que intentas hacer?

Comment: Si intentas parsear 2x3 con un parteInt te va a dar una excepción. Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, muestranos que has avanzado para que te podamos dar una respuesta adecuada a lo que lleves.